# Importing an external module in a global type definition file

Tags: meteor, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write a definition file for [meteor-files](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files), which is a Meteor Atmosphere package that exposes a global class `FilesCollection`. The start of my definition, I think, should look like this:

```
declare class FilesCollection extends Mongo.Collection<any> {
    constructor(config?: FilesCollectionConfig)
}
```

However, I'm not sure of the best way to reference `Mongo.Collection`. Here's an excerpt from the Meteor definition file:

```
declare module Mongo {
  var Collection: CollectionStatic;
  interface CollectionStatic {
    new < T > (name: string, options ? : {
      connection ? : Object;
      idGeneration ? : string;
      transform ? : Function;
    }): Collection < T > ;
  }
  interface Collection < T > {
    ...
  }
  ...
}

declare module "meteor/mongo" {
  module Mongo {
    var Collection: CollectionStatic;
    interface CollectionStatic {
      new < T > (name: string, options ? : {
        connection ? : Object;
        idGeneration ? : string;
        transform ? : Function;
      }): Collection < T > ;
    }
    interface Collection < T > {
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

So, when referencing `Mongo.Collection` elsewhere in my app, I start the file with `import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';`. However, I'm not sure how to do the same within a definition file, as I can't add an import statement in a global definition.

If I add Meteor as a global dependency in `typings.json`, the above appears to work in my definitions repository `typed-meteor-files`. However, when I use `typed-meteor-files` in my app, the additional properties from `Mongo.Collection` aren't pulled in, and I get the error `Cannot find Mongo` on the imported definition file. I'm a little lost, and not sure what the right way to do this is. Thanks!

Comment: Did you imported `Mongo` in `FilesCollection` definition file?

Comment: That's what I mean by 'can't add an import statement in a global definition'. If I have an import in the definition file, typings complains: `Attempted to compile "meteor-files" as a global module, but it looks like an external module.`